# What's the difference between a shame and a pity?

Tags: meaning

I have read a sentence

> It's a **shame** that the price of this book will put it beyond the reach of many readers.

Can I replace 'a shame' with 'a pity' without changing the substantial meaning?
If this replacement has changed the meaning of the whole sentence, what is the difference coming out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/40258/are-they-interchangeable-im-sorry-that-it-is-too-bad-that-and-its-a and/or http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/109986/can-it-is-a-shame-that-and-it-is-a-pity-that-be-used-to-describe-the-f  Also see a dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

One difference is *empathy* vs *guilt*

> It's a pity.

invokes feelings of empathy.

> He felt pity for the Syrian children caught up in the war.
>   *he felt compassion for the children suffering in Syria.*

> It's a shame.

invokes feelings of guilt.

> She felt shame that she could not help the children in Syria.
>   *she felt guilty that she could live comfortably but the children in Syria were suffering and there was nothing she could do.*

In your example, two possible different meanings might be

> It's a **shame** that the price of this book will put it beyond the reach of many readers.
>   *it's unfortunate that the price of  this book...*
>
> It's a **pity** that the price of this book will put it beyond the reach of many readers.
>   *it would be better if the price of this book was not beyond the reach...*